# Heat problem with an internal source of heat for which the maximum principle doesn't hold.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, applications

Heat problem with an internal source of heat for which the maximum principle doesn't hold. The problem is the following and honestly I don't know how to solve it...

$$u_{t}=u_{tt}+2(t+1)+x(1-x) ,   0<x<1, t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=0,   u(1,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=x(1-x),   0<x<1$$

$u(x,t)=(t+1)x(1-x)$ is a solution and there is a question: what are the maximum and minimum values of the initial and boundary data? And show that for some values of $t>0$, the temperature distribution exceeds M ( the maximum value) at certain points in the bar.

If you could help me please, thanks for your time and help everyone.

Comment: After correcting the typo, verifying that something is a solution is very easy: just plug it in to the PDE and the initial and boundary conditions.  As for finding maximum and minimum, that's just calculus.

Comment: Yes, I checked that u is that solution but the maximum principle it complicated

Comment: What's complicated about it?

Comment: Calculate the maximum and minimum value of the pde

Comment: It's not asking you to calculate the maximum or minimum of the solution.  It's asking: (1) Calculate the maximum and minimum values of the initial and boundary data.  (2) Show that u(x,y) can be greater than the maximum you calculated in (1).